# Postgres 'insert where not exists' from golang program

Tags: postgresql

I am having trouble with an 'insert where not exists' query from a Golang program. Here is my Go function:

```
func (dr *dbrepo) InsertData(datacenter, model, mgmt, data string) error {
    insertSource := `
INSERT INTO source (datacenter, model, mgmt, data)
VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT mgmt FROM source WHERE mgmt = $3)`

    _, err := dr.db.Exec(insertSource, datacenter, model, mgmt, data)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

It is giving this: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE" at character 77`

Any idea what is wrong with my postgresql insert syntax?

Comment: Have you tried manually running an example insert with that query directly in the db? That would be a good way to start debugging an issue like this.

Comment: I have @ScottNewson I was getting that same where syntax error. So, perhaps I am doing the wrong syntax on my query?

Comment: That suggests to me that this is a sql/postgres question and not related to Go at all

Comment: Correct. I removed the Go tag @ScottNewson

Comment: `INSERT` does not support `WHERE` in Postgresql.  You might be wanting `ON CONFLICT` but I don't know the syntax for that off hand.

Answer (score 0):

If there can not be more than one mgmt it means that it's unique, if it's unique - you can add ON CONFLICT to the insert command:

```
INTO source (datacenter, model, mgmt, data)
VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
ON CONFLICT(mgmt) DO NOTHING
```

to create mgmt as unique when creating the table:

```
create TABLE IF NOT EXISTS source (
    ...
    source text UNIQUE
);
```

read more about it [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) and about [unique](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createtable.html)

Edit: second option with stored procedure and plpgsql:

```
 create or replace function insert_if_not_mgmt(_datacenter text, _model text, _mgmt text, _data text) returns boolean as $$
begin
  if not exists (SELECT true FROM source s WHERE s.mgmt = _mgmt) then
    INSERT INTO source (datacenter, model, mgmt, data)
    VALUES (_datacenter, _model, _mgmt, _data);
    return true;
  end if;
  return false;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

the data types are just an example

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not unique. is there some other way I can do it?

Comment: @Jay266 can you use plgpsql? you can add if statement that wraps the insert

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE` is part of the [`SELECT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html) syntax. There is no `WHERE` clause for [`INSERT ... VALUES`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html).

Instead, you can use the `INSERT ... <query>` variant, where your query selects from a [`VALUES` expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-values.html):

```
INSERT INTO source (datacenter, model, mgmt, data)
SELECT * FROM (
  VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
) AS vals (datacenter, model, mgmt, data)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM source
  WHERE source.mgmt = vals.mgmt
);
```

Comment: Getting the following error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: inet = text at character 207. Does that mean I need to cast mgmt? mgmt is an INET

Comment: @Jay266: Yes, you'll need to cast something (you wouldn't have to with a plain `INSERT ... VALUES`; this is due to the difference between [`IMPLICIT` and `ASSIGNMENT` casts](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createcast.html)). Probably best to do it with a `CAST($3 AS INET)` in your `VALUES` list.